# access denied to github from rstudio

Tags: github, rstudio

After updating my personal access token I  can't push to Github.

The  error message that I get is:

```
>>> C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe push origin HEAD:refs/heads/main
remote: Permission to andreslagerlof/km2023.git denied to andreslagerlof.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/andreslagerlof/km2023.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I am using SSH and RStudio want to push to my GitHub account. I have also tried to see if I can access GitHub from the RStudio terminal

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi andreslagerlof! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I have also tried to push from the RStudio shell and got this message

```
AzureAD+AndrésLagerlöf@DESKTOP-CJSD5O2 MINGW64 /c/R_blogg/vc-2024
(master) $ git push AzureAD+Andr\303\251sLagerl\303\266f@github.com:
Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I have also updated my public key in my GitHub account (Settings > SSH and GPG keys).